# import matplotlib error on mac

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib

Um... I wanted to import matplotlib in Python IDLE, but it said

```
>>> import matplotlib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

I've already tried pip thing and the conda thing in terminal.
It said

```
# All requested packages already installed.
# packages in environment at /Users/Dan/anaconda:
```

Then! what's the problem here?

Comment: The"pip thing, conda thing"....how have you tried it?

Comment: Are you sure you installed matplotlib for the correct Python version?

Comment: And are you importing it from within the conda?

Comment: I put 'pip install matplotlib, conda install matplotlib' in terminal, but both of them didn't work. I installed anaconda for python 3.x.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may have installed Matplotlib to Python 2.7 and not Python 3.6. To install it to Python3 you need to use pip3:

```
pip3 install matplotlib
```

Then open python3.6 from your terminal (not idle) and try importing matplotlib from there. This way you can use any text editor you wish, and run your code from the terminal.

Comment: I already tried the first one, and I just tried the second one, but it didn't work. Same problem occured. I'm using Python 3.6, and I installed anaconda yesterday. The command that I used is terminal in mac.

Comment: As a test: open ipython from your terminal and try importing matplotlib from there

Comment: how can I open i python from terminal?

Comment: type 'ipython' into the terminal

Comment: 'import matplotlib' does work, but 'import matplotplib.pyplot as plt' doesn't.

Comment: ok so it is installed. When you tried installing matplotlib with pip originally, did you use pip3? I think matplotlib might be installed to the default python 2.7 on your system. You can test this by opening python 2.7 from the terminal and attempting to import matplotlib from there.

Comment: not sure. I just installed anaconda, and checked with pip. I put 'pip install matplotlib' in terminal and it said 'requirement already satisfied' for all programs(numpy, six, dateutil.....).

Comment: Yes, you need to use pip3 for it to install to your Python3.

Comment: Thanks. how can I do that?

Comment: If you ran "pip3 install matplotlib" then matplotlib should be available to import using Python3

Comment: Could you open python3 from within your terminal (not idle) and try importing matplotlib from there?

Comment: Ok great! That means if you use a text editor to code, and run that script from a terminal, it would work. I'm still unsure about why it won't import to idle though.

Comment: Thank you!! you're my lifesaver

Comment: You're welcome! I've edited my original answer to reflect this conversation, could you accept the answer? (green tick)

Comment: Because this is my first time to ask in stackoverflow, is accept your answer means click the check mark as what I did?

Comment: Yes, that is perfect.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue using the same command in IDLE. I just figured it out. go to your terminal and enter:

```
pip3.6 install matplotlib
```

I was using pip3 instead of pip3.6